# How to kill a running for loop on linux?

Tags: linux, pid

I'm working on Linux,
 I have executed the for loop on a Linux terminal as follows:

```
for i in `cat fileName.txt`
do
echo $i
vim $i
done
```

fileName.txt is a file contains the large no of file entries that I'm opening in vim editor one by one. Now i have to skip opening other files in between.(i.e. i have to break the for loop). Any suggestion how to get the PID of running for loop? and kill the same.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use PID and kill it, then your entire script will end, not only your loop. `ps -A | grep YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME` should give your process and its ID

Comment: Do you want to kill the file that you opened. Say fileName.txt has entries like 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt then once u open 1.txt , u want to kill that process ? Is that correct ?

Comment: @Pavan Thanks but I'm executing the for loop on the terminal itself not in any script.

Comment: @m4n07 i need to break the running "for" loop. it should not open the further files from the list present in fileName.txt.

Answer (score 15):

You want to kill the running **job**. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>. Bash will show something like:

```
[1]+  Stopped                 vim $i
```

Use that number with `kill` to send the `KILL` signal:

```
kill -9 %1
```

and it should be killed afterwards:

```
[1]+  Killed                  vim $i
```

Comment: This is the only way I've found to work for killing a shell loop in a terminal rather than a script. Thanks, I couldn't find the %n syntax elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

This might also do the trick:

```
while true ; do killall vim ; done
```

You can abort this one with ^C as usual.

Comment: Are you running this under the same user as the loop that spawns all the vims? Also, someone else might be running vim at the same time on the same machine, in which case you can ignore the error. `killall` will still kill whatever it can.

Answer (score 2):

Find the process id (PID) of the parent of the vim process, which should be the shell executing the for loop.  Try using "pstree -p".  Then, kill that process id using "kill ".

Answer (score 0):

To terminate the creation of the vim processes, you must stop the for loop. This loop is managed by a bash process. So find the PID of the process and kill it. To do so, find the PPID of a vim process, which is the PID of its parent process, and terminate the parent process :
`ps -elf | tr -s ' ' | grep vim | cut -f5 -d ' ' | xargs kill`

You can use this command with this second one, which will kill all vim processes, to ensure no vim instances remain:
`ps -elf | tr -s ' ' | grep vim | cut -f4 -d ' ' | xargs kill`

I see that you had a problem with "permission not permitted". This might be caused by a lack of permission, so to be sure it will kill the processes, you can call xargs kill with sudo : `ps -elf | tr -s ' ' | grep vim | cut -f5 -d ' ' | sudo xargs kill`